# Consistency in obeyspaces option for url package

Tags: spacing, footnotes, urls

I'm trying to make the `url` package use consistent spacing for the `\url{}` and `\path{}` commands, both in regular text and in footnotes. For this I use the `obeyspaces` option provided by the `url` package. Unfortunately, "Windows-style" paths give me trouble in footnotes by adding extra spacing before the backslashes. However, when I remove the `obeyspaces` option, the `\path{}` command concatenates all words inside into one long word, while the `\url{}` command is not affected. How do I make sure that Windows-style `\path{}`s don't add spacing in footnotes in the MWE below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,allowmove]{url}

\begin{document}

\path{C:\Users\Anthirian\Desktop\desktop.ini}\footnote{\path{C:\Users\Anthirian\Desktop\desktop.ini}}

\path{This path does not exist.}\footnote{\path{This path does not exist.}}

\url{https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf}\footnote{\url{https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

### `obeyspaces` enabled

[image: obeyspaces enabled]

### `obeyspaces` disabled

[image: obeyspaces disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url can not do its magic, if you use the commands in the argument of another command. In this case you should use `\urldef` to store the path first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,allowmove]{url}

\begin{document}
\urldef\mypath\path{C:\Users\Anthirian\Desktop\desktop.ini} 
\path{C:\Users\Anthirian\Desktop\desktop.ini}%
\footnote{\mypath} 
\path{This path does not exist.}\footnote{\path{This path 
does not exist.}} 

\url{https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf}\footnote{\url{https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

[image]